# why get https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId} and $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadSheetId) are different?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

If I get [https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?key={key}](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%7BspreadsheetId%7D?key=%7Bkey%7D) I have clear json like:

```
{ "spreadsheetId": "abc",
"spreadsheetUrl": "http://...",
"properties": { //basic data with "defaultFormat":{} },
"sheets": [{ // properties sheets }]
}
```

but if I in application write:

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadSheetId);
$json = json_encode((array)$response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I have different structure:

```
{ "spreadsheetId": "abc",
"spreadsheetUrl": "http://...",
"modelData":{ 
  "properties": { //basic data without "defaultFormat":{} },
  "sheets": [{ // properties sheets }]
  } 
}
```

why structure are different? how to improve it?

Comment: How do you make your request when you get ` https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?key={key} `?

Comment: I only send in chrome link and save json...

Comment: And how do you define `$service`? Are you sing heets API v4? Also, if the content of the respose is the same, why do you mind it being nested into `modelData`?

Comment: How can I check it?
config.php `$config = [
 'callback' => 'http://..../callback.php',
 'keys' => [
  'id' => GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  'secret' => GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
 ],
 'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
 'authorize_url_parameters' => [
  'approval_prompt' => 'force',
  'access_type' => 'offline'
 ]
];
$adapter = new Hybridauth\Provider\Google($config);`
callback.php
`adapter->authenticate();
 $token = $adapter->getAccessToken();
 $db = new DB();
 $db->update_access_token(json_encode($token));
 echo "Access token inserted successfully.";`

Answer (score 0):

### You are using a third party API

- If you build your `$service` object, as described in the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) of the official documentation for the Google Sheets API, you will get a response with a structure as expected:

```
{ "spreadsheetId": "abc",
"spreadsheetUrl": "http://...",
"properties": { //basic data with "defaultFormat":{} },
"sheets": [{ // properties sheets }]
}
```

- However, from what I can see, you are using a third party API [Hybrid_Auth](https://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/apidoc.html) that apparently returns you a modified response.